# exec-maven-plugin equivalent / alternative

Tags: bash, maven, exec-maven-plugin

In Maven, we can use `exec-maven-plugin` to execute bash commands in the build.

Which plugin of Central Repository can perform the same task?

I ask it because I have to execute a bash command after another plugin that needs to be executed in the same phase only after exec-maven-plugin, so I can't do it directly inside the exec-maven-plugin.

The bash command that I want to execute in the Maven build is the following:

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to write a plugin which is easier and cleaner to be integrated into the build process...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue with `maven-antrun-plugin` with the `<concat>` task:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>1.8</version> 
    <executions> 
        <execution> 
            <id>final step</id> 
            <phase>install</phase> 
            <configuration> 
                <target> 
                    <concat destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.sh" binary="yes"> 
                        <fileset file="${project.build.directory}/script/self-installer.sh" /> 
                        <fileset file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tar.gz" /> 
                    </concat>
                    <chmod file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.sh" perm="+x"/> 
                </target> 
            </configuration>    
            <goals> 
                <goal>run</goal> 
            </goals> 
        </execution> 
    </executions> 
</plugin>
```

This is the equivalent of the bash cat command.

Keep in mind that if you are concatenating a binary file, you have to set `binary="yes"`, otherwise the Ant task will corrupt the final file.

In any case, this is still not a bash-based solution, it's only a trick that uses Ant routines, so it's not a real equivalent of `exec-maven-plugin`